# How to correct my prime factorization program?

Tags: java, primes

Here is my program for outputting prime factorization of a given number. I am still just a beginner in java so I know it is not the most efficient code. The problem arises when I input relatively big numbers.

Input: 11 Output: 11

Input: 40 Output: 2 2 2 5

Input: 5427 Output: 3 3 3 3 67

Input: 435843 Output: 3 3 79 613

Input: 23456789 Output: none (there appears to be an infinite loop and the code should return 23456789 since it is a prime number on its own)

What might cause this issue?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeFactorization {
    public static boolean isPrime(long n) {
        boolean boo = false;
        long counter = 0;
        if (n == 1) {
            boo = false;
        } else if (n == 2) {
            boo = true;
        } else {
            for (long i = 2; i < n; i++) {
                if (n % i == 0) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            if (counter == 0) {
                boo = true;
            }
        }
        return boo;
    }

    public static void primeFactorization(long num) {
        for (long j = 1; j <= num; j++) {
            if (isPrime(j)) {
                if (num % j == 0) {
                    while (num % j == 0) {
                        System.out.printf(j + " ");
                        num = num / j;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (num == 1) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter any number:");
        long num = scanner.nextLong();
        System.out.print("Prime factorization of your number is: ");
        primeFactorization(num);
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the rest of your `primeFactorization` method; it looks like you have only copied the last part.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No matter how efficient the code, factorizing large numbers takes a while - so long it may feel like the computer has hung. Given your code, even modestly large numbers will take a long time.

The main thing you can do to improve your code's efficiency to to note that for any pair of factors of a number, one of them will be no more than the square root of the number. You can use this fact to limit the loop to reduce the order of you algorithm for O(n) to O(log n).

```
long sqrt = Math.sqrt(number);

for (long i = 2; i < sqrt; i++) {
    ...
```

There are many other things you can do, but this change will have the greatest effect.

If `number` changes value during the loop (as for example in your second factorizing loop), you'll if course need to recalculate the end value:

```
for (...)
    // if number changes
    sqrt = Math.sqrt(number);
```

Comment: This will be faster when `number` is prime or has just two factors.  It will be slower when `number` has many factors.  In the original algorithm, `num` is decreasing every time a factor is found, and every time a factor is found, there are fewer numbers left to divide by.  Your method fails to take this into account.  Now, as you get into higher and higher values of the original number, a larger and larger proportion of those values have multiple factors, and a smaller and smaller proportion are prime.  That means that in the general case, this change will actually make the performance ...

Comment: ... deteriorate, not improve it.  Of course, in the specific case where the original number is 23456789, this is an improvement, just because that number happens to be prime.

Comment: @david I not sure what point you are trying to make. Iterating from 2 to sqrt(num) takes less iterations than iterating from 2 to num - there's just no getting around that. It *must* be faster. As for the *second* loop, finding factors, I'm not suggesting that the contents of the loop be changed, just that the outer loop be capped to sqrt(num). Again, this *must* be faster than capping at num. As I said, there are more things that can be done, but going from O(n) to O(log n) with such a simple change is surely good bang for the buck.

Comment: Here, in more detail, is what's wrong with your answer.  Really not up to your usual standard, and I'm still trying to understand why I haven't downvoted it yet.  (1) I think you've misunderstood the OP's original code.  In the general case, it does not iterate all the way from 1 to n.  It iterates from 1 to the greatest prime factor of n.  So, for example, if n is 60 (which is 2 x 2 x 3 x 5), then it iterates from 1 to 5.  Whether your version is an improvement or not depends then on which is larger - sqrt(n) or the greatest prime factor of n.  Now for most small n, and for all ...

Comment: ... prime n, sqrt(n) will be smaller, so your code will be faster than the OP's.  But if n has lots of factors, your code will be slower than the OP's.  Now, as we get into larger an larger numbers, prime values become more and more sparse, as do values with very few factors.  So as n gets larger and larger, it becomes increasingly likely that your code is worse than the OP's, not better.  Your claim that it _must_ be faster is simply untrue - it is more likely to be slower, once n gets large enough.  (2) You claim that your algorithm is `O(log(n))` - not true.  It's at least `O(sqrt(n))`, ...

Comment: ...  which is considerably worse than `O(log(n))`. (3) You completely miss the most obvious thing of all - the OP's original algorithm contains a large number of completely redundant checks for primality.  These are computationally expensive, and since they're not needed at all, the best way to improve the efficiency of the code is to remove them.  Your answer misses this completely. (4) You claim that your change will have the "greatest effect".  Another untruth.  Removing the primality checks will always improve the performance substantially.  Your change will sometimes improve the ...

Comment: ... performance a little, sometimes not.  So to summarise my points, your answer consists of some advice which is sometimes useful, but more often worse than useless, and a couple of blatantly untrue assertions.  Bohemian, your answers are usually much better than this.

Comment: @david  I added a brief note to cover your point about the factorizing loop. I thought it was obvious to readers to recalculate the sqrt as required, but given the context of a beginner you're right - better to just say it. Assuming finding factors is required, it's still more efficient to recalculate the sqrt after finding each factor in case there are large factors. I did note that there are many things that can be done to improve performance, eg deleting the first loop entirely and instead trstings if there is only 1 factor doesn't change the big O, which was the biggest problem.

Answer (score 3):

There's no actual error - you're just doing things a very inefficient way.  Basically, you're checking every number between 1 and 23456789 for primeness, before dividing.

There's absolutely no point in doing this check.  As you work your way up from 1 to 23456789, each time you uncover a factor, you know it has to be prime, because you've already divided out all smaller factors.  So if you do all of the following, this will still work correctly, and much more quickly.

- Remove the `isPrime` method completely.
- Remove the line `if (isPrime(j)) {`, and the matching `}`
- Change the loop so that `j` starts at 2, like `for(long j = 2 ; j <= num ; j++) {`
- Remove `if (num == 1) { break; }` from the end of the loop.  It serves no purpose at all.

Comment: Your solution does not seem to work, now my code does not output any number for any given number, small or big.

Comment: Oh, you need to start `j` at 2 not at 1, otherwise you're just dividing by 1 over and over.  I'll edit the solution.